# Group action by conjugacy and "curves"

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group, $H\unlhd G$ and "$\cdot$" the $G$-action by conjugacy on $H$:

\begin{alignat*}{1}
  \cdot:G \times H &\longrightarrow H \\
  (g,h) &\longmapsto g \cdot h:= g^{-1}hg\\
\end{alignat*}

Say $g' \stackrel{h}{\sim} g \stackrel{(def.)}{\Longleftrightarrow} g' \cdot h = g \cdot h$. I see that $\stackrel{h}{\sim}$ is an equivalence relation in $G$.

My question is twofold (possibly merging together for something I'm missing):

1. Is there any link between the two partitions of $G$, namely $G/H$ and $\lbrace [g]_{\stackrel{h}{\sim}}, g \in G \rbrace$?
2. Given $\tilde g \in G, h \in H$, call $R_\tilde g(h):=[\tilde g]_{\stackrel{h}{\sim}}$ and $O(h):=\lbrace g^{-1}hg, g \in G\rbrace$; how is  $R_\tilde g(h) \cap O(h)$ made? In particular, is it empty?

Comment: Note that $g' \stackrel{h}\sim g$ if and only if $g^{-1} g'$ is fixed under conjugation with $h$.

Comment: @Christoph's comment can be re-phrased as: $G/C_{G}(h)=\lbrace [g]_{\stackrel{h}{\sim}}, g \in G \rbrace$, where $C_{G}(h)$ is the centraliser of $h$ in $G$ (all the elements of $G$ which commute with $h$). In general, $H$ and $C_G(h)$ are completely different (and $C_G(h)$ is not generally a subgroup of $H$, and nor in general will $H$ be a subgroup of $C_G(h)$). For example, if $h=1$ then $C_G(h)=Z(G)$, and this is independent on $H$ so take $H$ to be your favourite subgroup...

Comment: @Christoph Fixed!

Comment: @user1729 $C_G(1) = G$ not $Z(G)$. To get the center you'd consider $C_G(G)$.

Comment: Oops! Ah well, its too late to edit the question. But my point still stands: you can pick $h\in H$ such that $C_G(h)$ is completely unrelated to $H$.

Comment: Therefore, going now to my question 2 (edited in the meantime), we have that $R_\tilde g(h) \cap O(h) \ne \emptyset \Leftrightarrow \exists g' \in C_G(h), g'' \in G$ such that $g'\tilde g=g''^{-1}hg''$, i.e. $R_\tilde g(h) \cap O(h)=\lbrace g' \in C_G(h) \mid g'=g''^{-1}hg''\tilde g^{-1}, g'' \in G \rbrace$; also written in this way, I can't conclude... Do you?

Comment: According to $\stackrel{h}{\sim}$ definition, $g'\stackrel{h}{\sim}g$ iff $g'^{-1}hg'=g^{-1}hg$, so it seems to me that, e.g., $g\stackrel{h}{\sim}g$ for any $g$, am I lost?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: Well, given $h$, a sufficient condition to get a nonempty intersection is ($\tilde g \in C_G(h)) \wedge (g''=h\tilde g)$.